# Disable auto-population of the find field with selected text in Android Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I switch between IDEs and this is somewhat annoying.

Say I have selected "foo" in the source editor.

Copy -> Find -> Paste

Results in "foofoo" in the search field.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in IntelliJ, so it might be an Android Studio bug. You might consider skipping the paste though, since all occurences are marked after `Find` already.

Comment: It might be a Mac specific bug?  I know I should skip the paste, but it's just more consistent across all applications I use.

Comment: I HAVE THIS SAME PROBLEM.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, I think it's a feature. It's just a feature I want to somehow disable.

Comment: I have this issue as well. I don't think the problem is that it auto-populates. I think the problem is that it defaults to not being selected. So if you do Command+F and then start typing anything, it appends it to the selected text, instead of replacing it.